# where are output from console.XXX gets logged when using nodejs with opsworks?

Tags: node.js, logging, console, aws-opsworks

I am new to [AWS Opsworks](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/).  I have successfully deployed an app which was earlier being deployed through elastic beanstalk. The application is running, but I cant find any file where its console.log outputs are being saved.  I have grepped all files with .log extensions but cant find the output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think they just go to `stdout`, [this is what the node console docs say](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html).

aws-opswork may be a different thing though.

Comment: Yes, you're right: it outputs to the console / stdout, but that isn't captured anywhere.

See my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28229101/224334

Answer (score 0):

According to the [node.js stack docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/layers-server-nodejs.html):

> For more information about how to produce log files, see [How to log in node.js](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/intermediate/how-to-log).

I guess that apart from that, you could [override the the default recipe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/customizing.html), and since `monit` starts the node process, as seen in [opsworks-nodejs/templates/default/node_web_app.monitrc.erb](https://github.com/maciekish/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/a7cee1addf06a2fcc4af5d06f6f6c8319c12943e/opsworks-nodejs/templates/default/node_web_app.monitrc.erb#L2), change that to redirect the STDOUT to a file instead...