# Node.js OpsWorks Layer console logs

Tags: node.js, console.log, aws-opsworks, monit

I have an Opsworks stack with a Node.js Layer and Node.js Application. I'm wondering if anyone knows where on an ubuntu 14.04LTS instance the console logs from my application are being printed to. I know the opsworks uses monit to run my application but I'm not sure where its outputting the logs to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So annoyingly enough, the Monit configuration rendered for Node.JS apps on Opsworks doesn't send the output anywhere! [Source for this claim](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/opsworks_nodejs/templates/default/node_web_app.monitrc.erb#L2). (This surprised me when I learned about it!)

What I recommend doing is overriding that template - see [the OpsWorks documentation on overriding templates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-template-override.html): essentially all you need to do is copy paste the Monit config from Amazon, but change line 2 to redirect the output to a file, like I do below so:

`start program = "/bin/bash -c 'cd <%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current ; source <%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/shared/app.env ; /usr/bin/env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin PORT=<%= @deploy[:nodejs][:port] %> NODE_PATH=<%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current/node_modules:<%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current /usr/local/bin/node <%= @monitored_script %> &> <%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current/log/production.log'"`

Comment: thanks! yeah, thats weird that they don't send the output anywhere.

Comment: Thanks RyanWilcox! I've added a similar override to [aws-cookbook-boilerplate](https://github.com/dmarcelino/aws-cookbook-boilerplate/blob/master/opsworks_nodejs/templates/default/node_web_app.monitrc.erb#L2).

Comment: Thanks for this - but how do you access the log and where to look for it when you SSH to the instance? Thanks!

Comment: @Leo the logs will be saved at /srv/www/YOUR APP NAME/current/log/production . (Or what I do, hook that file up to be monitored by AWS CloudWatch Log - or a similar service - so you can use a web UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in the app directory then you will find this path shared/log

for example : `/srv/www/my_app/shared/log`

Answer (score 1):

I found the logs by doing the following (similar to @RyanWilcox's comment):

1. I found my "current" deployment in /srv/www/{APP NAME}/current/
2. listing files, I could see the log directory symlink (log should be
   symlinked to something like /srv/www/{APP NAME}/shared/log
3. I ran into a permissions issue trying to cd to this directory, so I
   switched to the super user without a password using the command "sudo
   su" and then I could access the directory
4. finally in the logs directory, I could see the nodejs console logs
   for STDERR and STDOUT

... and Bob's father is your father's father.

Answer (score -2):

Unless behavior of console.log was altered, `node` will output `console.log` logs to the application's standard output (`stdout`).
If you are running your node application in a console or using ssh, you should see the logs there.
Otherwise, try redirecting the stdout of your application to a file so you can see it even if you run it without a console, in this way:
`node myapp.js > logfile`

A preferred way would be to user [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to make sure you application is constantly on and there you can redirect your output (both stdout and stderr) as follows:

```
/>forever -o forever.out -e forever.err myapp.js
```